# Prevent value from changing on c

Tags: c, struct, static-libraries

I decided to make static library realising doubly linked lists with functions. Its header file is like this now:

```
#ifndef LISTS
#define LISTS

#define LIST {0, NULL, NULL}

typedef struct node node;

typedef struct list {
  unsigned int length;
  node *beginning;
  node *end;
} list;

void listAppend(list *list, int value);
int listPop(list *list);
char listRemove(list *list, int value);
void listPrint(list *list);

void listClear(list *list);

#endif
```

i.e. user should initialize list with `list myList = LIST;`.

Can I prevent list.length from casual changing by user in his code like `list.length++`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, if you want to hide implementation from client in pure C, you might use pointers to incomplete types. To do this, you put forward declaration of your struct in .h file and its full declaration in *.c file. You can't even add literal zero to a pointer to incomplete type, not to mention dereference it and/or alter some data.

Also, if you want to go against all odds and put your lists's header on stack, you might want to write a macro around [alloca()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html), however I'm not sure how to calculate size of your struct in *.h file without having its declaration in scope. it's possible via `extern const`, but IMHO it's too complicated.